# Is there a way to view data in RStudio data viewer and have labelled vectors showing value labels?

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-haven, r-labelled

I am using data in the form of a tibble with almost entirely categorical factors, each containing value labels for each factor levels. I would like to convert one of my factors to a labelled vector using the haven::labelled() command with value labels and a variable label specified. When the variable is in factor format, I can use the RStudio data viewer to view my tibble and see the value labels displayed, but when I convert the variable to a haven_labelled vector, the value labels do not appear in the data viewer, only the variable label. Is there a way to get the value labels for a haven_labelled vector to appear in the data viewer?

Also, I am planning to eventually export the tibble to various formats (csv, xlsx, dta) for my collaborators to use. Can anyone describe the nuances of representing variables as haven_labelled vectors with value labels vs. factors with value labels when exporting data and opening them in other applications like Excel, Stata?

Comment: Hi Zac, Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful you would please share a reproducible example including a small sample of your data set. You will likely get more helpful answers. You can do this best by using You can do this best by using `dput(head(my.example.data))`. Edit your question and include the output of the `structure(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, rstudios data viewer is not capable of showing value labels. You might write a feature request on github though. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

When you print a tibble with value labelled variables in the console, the (shortend) labels are shown side by side to the values.